# repo NOT set to continours integration in github

Tags: javascript, node.js

please i need your help, i have pushed my glitch website to github and finally push to heroku for deployment. When i did deployment i have some errors, and i come to understand that my repo was not set to continuous integration. now where in github can i navigate to set the repo to continous integration, before going back to deploy from heroku, thank you.

```
    //start server: node engine
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const compression = require('compression')
const dbInitiation = require("./construct/dbs");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config({path: "./.env"});
const userRoute = require("./routes/user");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');                            
const MemoryStore = require("memorystore")(session);
//set directory for views template files 
app.set('views', './views');
//set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
//middleware
app.use(compression())
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.SESSION_SECRET))
app.use(express.json());
require("./passport/local")(passport);

dbInitiation();

app.use(cookieParser())

const sessionStore = new MemoryStore({
   checkPeriod: 86400000
});

app.use(
session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
    key: "express.sid",
  store: sessionStore,  
}));
//
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//use routes function 
userRoute(app);
 
app.listen(process.env.PORT, function(req, res) {
  console.log("app running on port:", process.env.PORT);
});
```

Comment: Did you mean the auto deploy option on heroku?

Comment: yeah that is what i meant, auto deploy. now i am currently working with circleci orb to sent auto. but experience this error. though am hopping to solve it. I will like it if you assist in the auto deploy. thanks

Comment: If you have a repo linked to heroku, you can go to deploy > Automatic deploys and click on enable automatic deploys